# Auth missing in Preview API

Tags: spotify

I'd like to be able to connect to my Facebook App from within Spotify (Coke Highlights allows this).

However, in the Preview API (which I need for my app) it looks like authenticateWithFacebook is missing:

http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/09321954e7.html

The closest is:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-facebook-facebooksession.html

Where you can use showConnectUI, but that doesn't appear to work and is undocumented.

Comment: hi, I am fecing the same problem please help me if u find any solution on it

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` module was not present at first, but now it is part of the Spotify Apps API. You can read more about it on [its documentation page](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-auth-auth.html). It looks like this:

```js
  require(['$api/auth#Auth'], function(Auth) {
    var appId = '<your_app_id>',
        permissions = ['user_about_me'];

    var auth = new Auth();
    auth.authenticateWithFacebook(appId, permissions)
      .done(function(params) {
        if (params.accessToken) {
          console.log('Your access token: ' + params.accessToken);
        } else {
          console.log('No access token returned');
        }
      }).fail(function(req, error) {
          console.error('The Auth request failed with error: ' + error);
      });
    }
  });
```

In addition, there is [a working example](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/facebook/authenticate.html) in the [Tutorial App on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial).